# iOS UIDynamics attachment behavior showing the line

Tags: ios, uikit, uikit-dynamics

Is it a way to configure the UIDynamicBehaviors to show  the "line" that attaches two UIView using UIDynamics attachment behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [DynamicsCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) you can find on the apple developer website. You'll see a dashed line which will be drawn inside the class [APLDecorationView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Listings/DynamicsCatalog_APLDecorationView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013414-DynamicsCatalog_APLDecorationView_m-DontLinkElementID_18). `UIAttachmentBehavior` is just responsible for handling an attachment between specified elements not drawing any connections.

1. So if you want to use it inside your project, insert `APLDecorationView.h` 
   inside your file.
2. When your `UIViews` where the rope should be added, have been initialized, use following method:

   ```
   trackAndDrawAttachmentFromView:toView:withAttachmentOffset:
   ```
3. Customize inside the method the `UIImage` which should be displayed and maybe the size.

In my case it looked like this:

```
[(APLDecorationView *)self trackAndDrawAttachmentFromView:self.viewOne
                                                   toView:self.viewTwo
                                     withAttachmentOffset:CGPointZero];
```

And this is the modification of my `APDecorationView`:

```
    NSInteger iRopeElements = ( isiPad ) ? 15 : 20;
    for (NSUInteger i=0; i < iRopeElements; i++)
    {
        UIImage *ropeElement = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rope_element"];

        CALayer *layerRope = [CALayer layer];
        layerRope.contents = (__bridge id)(ropeElement.CGImage);
        CGFloat fRopeWidth = attachedView.frame.size.width * 0.3f;
        layerRope.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, fRopeWidth, fRopeWidth / 1.64f);
        layerRope.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0);

        [self.layer insertSublayer:layerRope atIndex:0];
        [self.attachmentDecorationLayers addObject:layerRope];
    }
```

Comment: How would I go about using it if I already had two UIImageView attached to each other. There is so little documentation...

Comment: Hey @Duffycola, just added some notes so you know how to use the code to create a dotted line in `UIDynamics`, if you have further questions, feel free to ask